# How to determine the upper and lower limit of the integral $\int\sqrt{a^{2}\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)+a^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}d\theta$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I was asked to find the length $L$ of the curve $r=a\cos(\theta)$,then I what I did is as follows:

$$L=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^{2}\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)+a^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}d\theta=a\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta=2a\pi.$$

It is assumed that $a$ is positive.

However the real answer is $a\pi$,I don't understand how do we determine the upper and lower limits of such integrals,does there exist anyway to do that without plotting the graph of the function (which is a circle)?

---

Updated

I don't know how to prove the formula which we use to compute the length of a curve,but all I know is based on Thomas Calculus (12th).
[image]

Comment: Cut off cases when $r=\cos\theta <0$ by showing they duplicate cases for $r=\cos\theta >0$

Comment: What do you mean by the equation $a=\cos(\theta)$? What is here $a$? What coordinate system is used?

Comment: If one assumes that your curve is $r=a\cos\theta$ in polar coordinates, then what you computed is the length of some other curve. Try to guess which one.

Comment: $\theta$ does not take all values from $0$ to $2\pi$ because $r$ is always positive.

Comment: Check the spelling of your function - is it really  $a=\cos \theta?$ Is $a$ the radius in polar coordinates? If yes, then $a\geq 0$ which reduces the interval for $\theta.$

Answer (score 2):

Since $r\ge0$, $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\,\pi/2]$ is an appropriate  integration range, whereas $\theta\in[0,\,2\pi]$ is not. So$$r=a\cos\theta\implies r^2+(dr/d\theta)^2=a^2\implies L=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}ad\theta=a\pi.$$In fact, $x^2+y^2=r^2=ar\cos\theta=ax\iff (x-a/2)^2+y^2=(a/2)^2$ is a radius-$a/2$ circle, of circumference $a\pi$.

Comment: How do we know that $r$ is not negative?besides what is $s$?can you tell me what is the meaning of $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2=a^2d\theta^2$, and where does that come from?

Comment: @number Well, how did _you_ realize you had to integrate $\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}$, if not by using [this](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/m408d/CurrentWeb/LM10-4-4.php)? if you let $\cos\theta$ change sign with $\theta\mapsto\theta+\pi$, $(x,\,y)=(a\cos^2\theta,\,\tfrac12a\sin2\theta)$ will be the same point, so you'd erroneously measure the curve twice.

Comment: I still don't know what is $s$ and how do we know that $r$ is positive,can you just explain alittle easier,I'm so new to these kind of questions.

Comment: @number If you edit your question to show how you got your formula for $L$, I'll update my answer to give an explanation in similar terms.

Comment: I edited,however I'm not sure if that helps,since I don't know the whole proof

Comment: @number I've also edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that,what is the meaning of $r^2+(dr/d\theta)^2=a^2$ and how that implies $L=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}ad\theta=a\pi$

Comment: @number You obviously knew what it meant when using the formula.

Comment: I just memorized the formula,that's all

Comment: @number If you want to ask what that formula means or how it's proven, you should ask a new question.

Comment: As I know $r=\pm\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$,I don't see any reason why $r$ is necessarily non-negative,how are we sure about that?you say since $r\ge0$ ...,this looks that it's a secret that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @number That $\pm$ is spurious. Polar coordinates have $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge0$ so, for points other than the origin, $\cos\theta,\,\sin\theta$ have the respective signs of $x,\,y$.

Comment: So negative $r$ is meaningless?

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{a^{2}\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)+a^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}d\theta=a\int_{=\pi/2}^{\pi/2}d\theta=a\pi.$$

Paul's on-line Calc. For circle *diameter* $a=4$. You can see the $\theta$ limits are $\pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ on either side of x-axis or $\theta =0 $ axis

[image]